# understanding bitonic sort code

Tags: c++, c

The following code for bitonic sort works correctly. I need some explanation of the code present inside the inner-most for loop. I understand that the logic is based on arranging elements in ascending and descending order alternatively forming 2 element bitonic sequence, 4 element bitonic sequence, 8 element bitonic sequence and so on. But I don't understand how the code is able to achieve this, particularly the xor operation and if statements before the swaps.

```
void bitonic_sort(int *data, int N)
{

    int i, j, k;
    int temp;

        for (k = 2;k <= N;k = 2 * k) 
        {
            for (j = k >> 1;j>0; j = j >> 1) 
            {
                for (i = 0;i<N;i++) 
                {
                    int ixj = i^j; 

                    if ((ixj)>i)
                    {
                        if ((i&k) == 0 && data[i] > data[ixj]) {
                            temp = data[i];
                            data[i] = data[ixj];
                            data[ixj] = temp;
                        }

                        if ((i&k) != 0 && data[i] < data[ixj]) {
                            temp = data[i];
                            data[i] = data[ixj];
                            data[ixj] = temp;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }   

}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @Vandana why not take a look to the [wiki Bitonic sorter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) ? The inner-most for loop is called kernel().